# How Can I Put Another Value On Another Input Text

Tags: php, jquery, typeahead

refers to this link:

https://gist.github.com/awgreenblatt/4499835

How can i put the value if i have 3 different input text like:

```
<input id="product_search[1]" type="text" data-provide="typeahead"><br>
<div id="product[1]" style="border-width:1; padding: 5px; border-style: solid"></div><br><br>

<input id="product_search[2]" type="text" data-provide="typeahead"><br>
<div id="product[2]" style="border-width:1; padding: 5px; border-style: solid"></div><br><br>

<input id="product_search[3]" type="text" data-provide="typeahead"><br>
<div id="product[3]" style="border-width:1; padding: 5px; border-style: solid"></div><br>
```

Thank you

Comment: Which value and where do you want to put it?

Comment: The inputs use `val()` instead of `html()`, so you'd do: `$("input").val("Value you want to fill");`. However you're referring to "the value", which'd mean in English that you have already told us what value, but this is not the case. What value do you want to fill in?

Comment: when autofill click, the values are in <div></div>.

on that link, just have 1 <input text>, everything looks great.
but if i create 2 or more <input id=product_search[]>,it doesn't work, even autofill too.

i don't know how to fix it,
please,
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

taken from the link you provided

```
var products = [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: "Deluxe Bicycle",
                price: 499.98
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Super Deluxe Trampoline",
                price: 134.99
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Super Duper Scooter",
                price: 49.95
            }
        ];

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#product_search1').val(products[0].name);
   $('#product_search2').val(products[1].name);
   $('#product_search3').val(products[2].name);
});
```

the fact that i tested with jsFiddle, my solution wont with your ID's. you might want to rename your input Id's

jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/KVS5F/

Comment: on jsfiddle.net/KVS5F autofill it could not run.

i want it still run like this link https://gist.github.com/awgreenblatt/4499835
but i still can create 2 or more <input text> with a different id.